# php htaccess url rewrite issue

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Im trying to get a url rewrite to work and Im not getting any where. basically I want to have three pages one for music and then general products and the other for mvies, each will have a query string of &pagetype=general etc but the url would be http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/browse/computers.html?pageType=general which will redirect to general_products.php and then there would music_products and also movie_products. So they all have the same url except there is a different parameter &pageType=. Below is my htaccess file this is my first attempt at doing this

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])\.html general_products.php?department=$1&pageType=general
RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])\.html music_products.php?department=$1&pageType=music
RewriteRule ^browse/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])\.html movie_products.php?department=$1&pageType=movie

url suppose to look like this
http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/browse/computers.html
```

All Im getting is an error for each url rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much htacess, but I used it lately and I found out that you can't actually use "/" effectively. I suggest you change it for "_".

As far as I understand, it may be due the "/" works as the one indicating each argument (I mean A / B sorta logic)

Not sure if I explain myself correctly, hoping someone knowledgeable corrects me since I'm eager to learn about it as well.

RewriteRule ^browse_computers / general_products.php?department=$1&pageType=general ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])

RewriteRule ^browse_music / music_products.php?department=$1&pageType=music ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])
RewriteRule ^browse_movies / movie_products.php?department=$1&pageType=movie ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])

The result, however, will be this: 
http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/browse_computers

Comment: I tried that and I still get an error. I still want to have it look like this url  http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/browse/computers.html?pageType=general

Answer (score 0):

Bit unsure of your initial url but try this

^browse_(.+)/(.+)$ browse/computers.html?pageType=$1